# How to use QueryStringQueryBuilder

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nosql, kibana

I've tried to use QueryStringQueryBuilder in a very simple case, but I dont understand why I get another result than the result I get from Kibana. What am I doing wrong?

Kibana:

```
GET .../_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "\"this is a query\"",
            "lenient": true,
            "default_operator": "OR"
        }
    }
}
```

Java:

```
private Optional<QueryStringQueryBuilder> parseQuery(String query) {
    if (query.equals("")) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    QueryStringQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query);
    queryBuilder.lenient(true);
    queryBuilder.defaultOperator(Operator.OR);
    return Optional.of(queryBuilder);
}
```

Result from kibana: totalhits = 3336. Result from Java: totalhits = 10018.

EDIT:
This method calls parseQuery. Input is "this is a query".

```
public Optional<SearchRequestBuilder> getRequestBuilderByQuery(SearchQuery query) {
        SearchRequestBuilder builder = getBuilderWithMaxHits(query.getMaxHits());
        builder.setFetchSource(Globals.getFIELDS(query.isIncludeStory()), new String[0]);
        parseQuery(query.getQuery()).ifPresent(builder::setQuery);
        return Optional.of(builder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your input parameter 'query' in this case contains.

But i think you want to set `queryBuilder.queryName(String queryName)` in your `QueryStringQueryBuilder`.

From the JavaDocs:

> queryName(String queryName):
>   Sets the query name for the filter that can be used when searching for matched_filters per hit.

Comment: The query is the same in both examples. The query can be something like : "this that" OR this AND that NOT this. But i started using only a quote query.


Im using queryStringQueryBuilder because I thought it might parse the query by itself with the keywords AND,OR,NOT

So the input in parseQuery is(in this example)  "this is a query"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.
The query for kibana had quotation marks. Which meant it was processed differently than just a normal String. QueryStringQuerybuilder seems to be parsing the query by itself with "",AND,OR,NOT. This is magic!